# What is the meaning of the verb “willed” in the following context:

Tags: word-meaning, figurative-language

Douglas Robson, [USA TODAY Sports](http://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/tennis/french/2014/06/07/maria-sharapova-beats-simona-halep-french-open/10162357/) says:

> The favorite when defending champion Serena Williams toppled out in the second round, Sharapova virtually willed her way to the title.

I think in this context willed is the simple past of the verb “to will” (not the modal “will”). Yet I can’t figure out from the [dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/willed) which sense is more appropriate.

Comment: I think this *will* express strong desire or determination. According to your link, I think "will2", senses 9 and 10 are quite close to the intended meaning.

Comment: @DamkerngT. You got it - post it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this *will* expresses strong desire or determination. According to your [link (Dictionary.com)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/willed), I think *will* <sup>2</sup>, senses 9 and 10 are quite close to the intended meaning.

> **will<sup>2</sup>**
>
>   ***verb (used with object),* willed, will·ing.**
>   9. to decide, bring about, or attempt to effect or bring about by an act of the will: *He can walk if he wills it.*
>   10. to purpose, determine on, or elect, by an act of will: *If he wills success, he can find it.*

The next paragraphs in [that post (USA TODAY)](http://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/tennis/french/2014/06/07/maria-sharapova-beats-simona-halep-french-open/10162357/) make it quite clear that she really needed a strong will to succeed in this French Open.

> She was pushed to three sets in her last four matches but never folded, always finding a solution and an extra gear. [...]
>   Against Halep, she needed to go the distance again.

The final match was 3 hours and 2 minutes long, and obviously not easy, but she prepared herself for it as [she said a few days before the match](http://tennis.si.com/2014/06/05/maria-sharapova-eugenie-bouchard-french-open-semifinals/),

> "I would love to win those matches in two sets, but I always feel like I put in the work to be ready to play whatever it takes. If it takes three hours to win the match in three sets, I will be ready for that."

As an aside, the phrase "*verb* one's way to ..." is also interesting. It seems like you can apply almost any verb to the phrase. For example, besides something obvious like *making your way to your bedroom*, you can ***[sleep your way to the top](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20334/to-sleep-your-way-to-the-top)***, *work your way to success*, *trade your way to financial freedom*, *laugh your way to a better marriage*, *talk your way to the top*, *think your way to a better life*, and obviously, ***will your way to the title***.

Answer (score 1):

The literal meaning is that Sharapova reached the title by a sustained act of willpower—that is, by a mental act having direct control over the results of the tournament. If you try, by mental exertion alone, to move a glass across a table without touching it, that is the sense of `to will` intended here.

However, this is a deliberately exaggerated, figurative description, as indicated by the word `virtually`. Of course the author doesn't mean that Sharapova *really* willed her way to the title; such a thing is not possible. The figurative sentence exaggerates a more ordinary sort of willpower shown by Sharapova, described in the following paragraphs: she found strength during long, exhausting matches ("an extra gear"—more figurative language); she overcame an early setback ("broken in the opening game") by "lifting her level" (responding to the setback by playing more skillfully); and she never let up the pressure on her opponent.

The most relevant senses at [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/willed) are:

> 12. to influence by exerting will power: *She was willed to walk the tightrope by the hypnotist.*
>
> 13. to exercise the will: *To will is not enough, one must do.*

What's really being described does happen to fit under some of the other senses given there, like numbers 9 and 10, but those aren't the most relevant senses of the word (or else there'd be no need to say `virtually`). But those senses are still relevant. This is loose, figurative language, summarizing some more-specific facts that follow. It doesn't have a completely precise meaning.